# Update query not working but the code seems fine

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the Query string I am using, i have tried many different itterations...

```
if (!mysqli_query($db_connection,'UPDATE `questions` SET 
`question`='.$question.', `answer1`='.$answer1.', `answer2`='.$answer2.', 
`answer3`='.$answer3.', `answer4`='.$answer4.', `rationale`='.$rationale.', 
`resources`='.$resources.' WHERE `question_id`='.$id))
            {
                echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db_connection));
            }
```

this is the error I get:

> Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax.

I have tried using single quotes, double quotes without ` and with.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I would suggest using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Other than preventing SQL injection, it removes a lot of headaches since it removes the need to worry about quoting your variables.

Comment: As aynber says, using prepared statements would probably solve the issue here as you don't need to deal with the quoting. Update to that and if the problem persists, edit to show the resulting problem.

Comment: There's usually a little more to that error message .... something about `near ..` which can help pinpoint where you're going wrong. But, as has already been pointed out, prepared statements are the way to go.

Comment: thanks everyone i will try these!... im not concerned about injection... this is on a dev server only i have access to and I will only be running this script once and deleting the file when its complete.  this is not going on a  production page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a case of using single or double quotes but doing both correctly, you need to wrap your strings in double quotes and open and close your concatenation with singles eg ’answer’ = " ' .$variable. ' ", .....  Then the quotes become part of your string.

Comment: But also, you need to use pdo, to quote Charlie from Top Gun I think we've shown this as an example of what not to do...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE `questions` SET question`='{$question}',`answer1`='{$answer1}', `answer2`='{$answer2}', `answer3`='{$answer3}', `answer4`='{$answer4}', `rationale`='{$rationale}', `resources`='{$resources}' WHERE `question_id`=".$id);
if ($query)
{
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db_connection));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the comments stated prepared statements is the way to go. You are open to SQL injection.

Secondly, as for the mysql error message, It looks like you are missing a single quote at the end of your query. `WHERE question_id='.$id`. Also Echo out the query string and you'll notice that your query does not have single quotes around your parameters. You are using single quotes to create the query string but not for the query parameters. Use double quotes for the query string, and single quotes for the parameters:

```
"UPDATE `questions` SET 
`question`='".$question."', `answer1`='".$answer1."', `answer2`='".$answer2."', 
`answer3`='".$answer3."', `answer4`='".$answer4."', `rationale`='".$rationale."', 
`resources`='".$resources."' WHERE `question_id`="'.$id."'"
```